# Can't write long JSON output to text file

Tags: python, json

I have a long string (8,315 characters) worth of JSON, but I can't seem to write it to a .txt file using Python without it being truncated.

I write the JSON to a text file and then upload it via FTP, but both the .txt file on my system and the .txt file on the FTP server are truncated.

Here's the code:

```
# Upload the results
host = ftputil.FTPHost('ftp.website.com', 'username', 'password')
jsonOutput = json.dumps(full_json)
f = open('C:/Comparison.txt', 'w')
f.write(jsonOutput)
host.upload('C:/Comparison.txt', '/public_html/Comparison.txt')
f.close()
print jsonOutput
```

The JSON output in the console is valid and whole, but it is truncated in the .txt file that is written (and then the .txt file after it is uploaded).

Most of the time, the output will end at `http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/A000073/1050-10` when the full URL is actually `http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/A000073/1050-1041-ND/3476357` (and then of course, it cuts off the rest of the JSON)

I'm not sure if this makes any difference, but I also tried `f.write(re.escape(jsonOutput)` with the same results.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Short answer: Close the file before you upload it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
with open('C:/Comparison.txt', 'w') as f:
  json.dump(full_json, f)
```

Comment: any particular reason why this works and `json.dumps` doesn't? Also, does it need to be opened as `wb` instead of `w`?

Comment: @JeffTratner: Due to buffering `f.write()` doesn't right at once to disk until `f.close()`. `with`-statement closes the file on exit.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian okay, so I guess `json.dump` is interacting with the file object differently? (and doing something like `f = open(...); json.dump(full_json, f); f.close();` would be equivalent to this answer, right?

Comment: @Jeff: That was actually my old answer. I decided that using `with` would be clearer.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams , it's definitely clearer, just trying to understand the difference between `json.dump` and `json.dumps` :P

Comment: @JeffTratner: `json.dumps` doesn't interact with the file at all. It just produces a string. It doesn't care what you do with it. `json.dump` just calls `f.write()`. The only difference that it can call it multiple times with smaller parts. Your problem is unrelated to `json`. Only buffering (file's `bufsize` parameter) and the time `f.flush()` or `f.close()` are called matters.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, got it, don't know why it took me so long-- def a "duh" moment for me there. Thanks for taking the time to answer.